# How do I get average temperatures and precipitation data into QGIS or SAGA GIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, saga, weather, openweathermap-api

I need average temperatures and precipitation data (if possible as grid) for Germany and I found this source:  https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/

But I have no idea on how to load it into QGIS or SAGA GIS I'm working with.
Does anybody here know how to use this data?

Answer (score 4):

1) Go up in the file structure, for example this here:
https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/halfyear/precipitation/

2) Download the file, in the case of the link above: grids_germany_halfyear_precipitation_201819.asc.gz

3) Than unpack the downloaded gzip file (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) - I used [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) on Windows, please see what kind of software you can use on your machine.

4) The resulting file in this case is RSMS_19_2018_01.asc : Drag and drop this file into the QGIS-window (or use menu layer - add raster layer and look for the file on your drive).

The resulting layer looks like this:

[image]